# Keeping shortcode-generated widget and theme element in one line

Tags: widgets, sidebar, plugin-polylang

I set up a playground site [PlaygroundSite](http://polnets.c0.pl/home/)

and I am trying to put Polylang language changer widget in the same line as linked-in icon.
Because ascent theme does not contain a widget/sidebar area there, I used amr shortcode any widget plugin to insert shortcode function into header.php.

Unfortunately, you it does not work OOTB and you can see results on site.
I also would love to get rid of that bullet (indicator) on the left of the flag.

The code I use for inserting:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[do_widget id=polylang-4]'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get rid of the bullets and change the alingment you'll need CSS.

For the top portion:

```
aside.widget_polylang.amr_widget,
aside.widget_polylang.amr_widget ul,
aside.widget_polylang.amr_widget li {
  /** align with li */
  display: inline-block;
  float:right;
  /** remove bullets */
  list-style: none;
}

ul.social-icons {
  /** align with li */
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
}
```

For the bottom portion:

```
aside.widget_polylang li {
  /** remove bullets */
  list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I modded my CSS with your code and have an effect.
I have one more question, adding widget generates additional line below it. Is is a part of CSS or maybe a method how Polylang handle its widget?
(I mean, the grey field is too high)

Comment: I don't understand the question.
Due to adding widget it became too high, so your code did not make this additional space fortunately :)

Comment: It think it's not very clear what you're going for. Maybe you should upload an image of how it looks and what you're wanting it to look like.

Comment: http://imgur.com/zDDTKDg

Adding Flag generated additional grey space.

Comment: You have a bunch of stuff going on. Use Chrome Tools to view the computed layout and install https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pesticide-for-chrome/bblbgcheenepgnnajgfpiicnbbdmmooh?hl=en-US which will show you all the elements that are acting out.